# JavaScript filter and reduce on array to concatenate string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use **filter** and **map** concept instead of iterating over an array using {for} loop.

Here is my old code. I am passing an array to filter and combine matching strings.

```
function oldFunction(data) {
    let dataDeleted = '';
    let each
    for (each of data) {
        if (each.includes('_DELETE')) {
            dataDeleted = dataDeleted + each.substring(0, each.length - 7) + '###';
        }
    }
    dataDeleted = dataDeleted;
    console.log(dataDeleted);
}

oldFunction(['meow_DELETE', 'haga', 'Neigh_DELETE']);
```

The output is: `'meow###Neigh###'`

Now when i try with 'filter' and 'reduce' method, it doesn't seem to work:

```
function newMethod(data) {

    const dataDeleted = data
        .filter(d => d.includes('_DELETE'))
        .reduce((deletedData, d) => {
            deletedData.concat(`${d}### `);
        }, '');

    console.log(dataDeleted);
    return dataDeleted;

}
```

This is returning 'undefined'. Any pointers ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you just need to `return` the data in your reducer function.

```
.reduce((deletedData, d) => {
   return deletedData.concat(`${d}### `);
}, '')
```

or using shorthand version:

```
.reduce((deletedData, d) => deletedData.concat(`${d}### `), '')
```

Comment: Thanks @quantastical.. this worked. Also, was wondering if I need to have _DELETE removed from the string and print [meow,Neigh] , can i do it in the same reduce function ?

Comment: Yes you could do `\`${d.replace('_DELETE', '')}### \``. Basically the `${...}` is just more javascript. If you don't want to jam it all into a single line like that you could break it out into multiple statements, i.e. `(deletedData, d) => { var clean = d.replace('_DELETE', ''); return deletedData.concat(\`${clean}### \`)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach using `join()` and `concat()` instead of `recude()` as reduce internally iterates the array, if that's what you want to avoid for whatever reason. <s>One would have to test the performance of both approaches to see which one is preferrable.</s>

**Update:** I actually [did just that on JSperf](https://jsperf.com/reduce-vs-join-concat) and my approach is about 60-70% *slower* than Quantastical's, so you should definitely stick to that.

**Update2:** I updated the code to meet the new requirements from the comment, now only using `filter()` and `reduce()`.

```js
function newMethod(data) {

    const dataDeleted = data
        .filter(d => d.includes('_DELETE'))
        .reduce((deletedData, d) => {
          return deletedData.concat(`${deletedData.length ? '###' : ''}${d.replace(/_DELETE$/, '')}`);
        }, '');

    console.log(dataDeleted);
    return dataDeleted;

}
newMethod(['meow_DELETE', 'haga', 'Neigh_DELETE']);
```

Comment: Hey @Connum, if I would like to have _DELETE removed, and instead print 'meow###Neigh'.. can i do it in the same reduce method ?

Comment: I updated the code in my answer to meet the new requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
function newMethod(data) {

    const dataDeleted = data
        .filter(d => d.includes('_DELETE'))
        .reduce((acc, d) => {
            return acc.concat(`${d}### `);
        }, '');

    return dataDeleted;

 }
```

Comment: hey @Valerii,  if I would like to have _DELETE removed, and instead print 'meow###Neigh'.. can i do it in the same reduce method ?